# Unable to execute R code on U-SQL using R extensions

Tags: r, azure, u-sql

I have been trying to execute R code on U-SQL using the R extensions mentioned in the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-analytics/data-lake-analytics-u-sql-r-extensions).

When I try to execute the example scripts mentioned in the link above, it throws the error:

```
C# error CS1739: The best overload for 'Reducer' does not have a parameter named 'rReturnType'
```

And when I remove the `rReturnType` parameter I am unable to make sense of the output.

Are there any other Extension.R parameters which will serve the same purpose?

Comment: In order to execute it locally you have to do this before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52333878/install-azure-u-sql-extensions-to-run-r-python-scripts-locally/52333879#52333879

Answer (score 1):

Which version of the extensions have you installed? if you installed them some while ago, the parameters of the libraries may have changed and be out of date with the documentation. I am pinging the owner of the documentation page to make sure that the docs are in sync with the latest released version.

**UPDATE**: I checked and the documentation is aligned with the latest version. Please go to the ADLA Portal and reinstall the U-SQL Extensions. Please make sure that you read up on the [release notes](https://github.com/Azure/AzureDataLake/blob/master/docs/Release_Notes/2017/2017_Summer/USQL_Release_Notes_2017_Summer.md) in case you or someone else uses the older version.